# Ignore or silence QThread warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pyside, qthread

I have an application in python that uses PySide for the GUI. To keep the application responsive, I have a lot of threading.

Some of the threads are daemon threads that are meant to work forever, some are also daemon threads that we don't care if they finish. Application works fine, the responsiveness is OK, but the problem is with the exit code. When there is a thread that is still running during application exit, I got a following message: `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`. The message is not a problem, but the problem is that it causes application to exit with exit code 1 which breaks our CI builds.

We don't care about the threads that are still running, and some of them we cannot stop by setting a flag. 
We've tried to terminate the thread by using `terminate()` method from the QThread, but it seems to not do anything. Of course we executed `setTerminationEnabled(True)` for the thread and even waited for few seconds. The `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running` was there every time. To maintain the references to the threads I have a global list of all of them, which allows me to make sure that all threads are terminated, but still the terminated threads have `isRunning()` return `True` and `isFinished()` return `False`. Sometimes I get `Fatal Python error: This thread state must be current when releasing` on attempt to `terminate()`.

Here is a sample code to reproduce this behavior:

```py
import sys
import time

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    def run(self):
        print("start process")
        while True:
            # in reality there is no while loop, it is just a long running process
            # which may not finish before user decides to close the application
            print("running")
            time.sleep(2)


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.app = app

        self.thread = Thread()
        self.thread.start()
        print("Control is back in main thread.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget(app)
    w.show()
    # the line below can be commented-out to see result immediately
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you close the application, the script will exit with code 1 and `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running message`.

Is it possible to tell QT to just silently kill such dangling threads without any warnings? Basically, I want the daemon thread functionality which is allowed in standard Python threading. Is there any way to replicate it in QT? There isn't any mention about daemon threads in any docs.

Comment: @eyllanesc - could you remove the duplicate mark from this question? I think you now understand that it is completely different problem.

Comment: @Djent If you have monolithic worker threads that cannot be interrupted, there is no clean way to terminate them (in python). For those cases, you should use a separate *process* instead - i.e. [use multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: OK, the functionality I want to achieve is basically a daemon thread, which is supported by Python threading. I think that it just isn't available in QT.

Comment: no answer yet? It's been a year. I'm facing the same problem but with an open file dialog triggering this. I'm gonna start a new question then